# In SwiftUI on Apple Watch, what is the best way to update a String that describes the interval since a Date with Always On State?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I'm building an Apple Watch app that uses SwiftUI.

New data periodically comes into the app from an outside source, and I keep track of when that last happened with a `@Published` `Date` (called `lastUpdatedDate`) inside an `ObservableObject` (`store`).

In the app, I want to use a SwiftUI `Text` struct to indicate to the user how long ago the data was updated.

I'm weighing different options, and I'm wondering what the best practice would be for something like this.

## Solution #1 - Text.DateStyle

A very simple method I tried was using `Text.DateStyle.relative`:

```
Text(store.lastUpdatedDate, style: .relative)
```

This worked the way I wanted to some degree, because it kept the text up-to-date with the relative interval since the date had happened, but [the text is not customizable](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652201). I do not want it to show the number of seconds, just minutes or hours.

## Solution #2 - Computed Property

Inside the `View` where I want to display the `Text`, I have access to the `ObservableObject`, and added a computed property that uses a function that converts the `Date` to a `String` for the relative date (for example, *5 minutes ago*) using an `extension` on `Date` with a `RelativeDateTimeFormatter`

Computed property:

```
private var lastUpdatedText: String {
    store.lastUpdatedDate.timeAgoDisplay()
}
```

Date extension:

```
extension Date {
    func timeAgoDisplay() -> String {
        let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        return formatter.localizedString(for: self, relativeTo: Date())
    }
}
```

This seems like the best solution I've found so far, because it automatically updates every time the app is opened. The downside, however, is that it only seems to update when the app comes to the foreground (when another app or the Clock Face was previously active). This is probably fine, but it could be better on Series 5, Series 6, and Series 7, which have alway-on displays. On watchOS 8, with the [Always On State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/designing_your_app_for_the_always_on_state), this text remains on the screen when the wrist is dropped, and when the wrist is raised again. The text can become outdated, because these events do not cause the `lastUpdatedText` computed property to be updated again.

**Update:** This is actually not a very good solution. Through more testing, I found out that it is a fluke that it was updating every time the app opened. It was only re-computing the property on app open because other items in the view were getting refreshed, and on its own it would not have actually re-computed every time the app was opened.

## Other Possible Solutions

I've considered adding a second `@Published` variable in the `ObservableObject` that's a `String` containing the relative time interval. The downside of this is I would have to manually initialize and update that variable. If I do that, I could manually update the text based on lifecycle functions in ExtensionDelegate, like `applicationWillEnterForeground()`, but that only handles when the app first comes to the foreground (which is the same update frequency as the computed property). I haven't found any way to detect when the wrist is dropped or raised again, so it seems the only way I could keep it up to date is to set up one or more published `Timer`s, and update the `@Published` `String` every minute, disabling and setting up the timer(s) every time the app goes into the background and returns to the foreground. Does that seem like a good solution? Is there a better solution I'm overlooking?

---

## Solution

Based on the accepted answer, I was able to use a `TimelineView` to update periodically.

Even though I am only using minute granularity for the text that's displayed, I wanted the text to update to the second when the data was actually refreshed. To accomplish that part, I started by adding a new `extension` for `Date`:

```
extension Date {
    func withSameSeconds(asDate date: Date) -> Date? {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var components = calendar.dateComponents([.era, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: self)
        let secondsDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.era, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
        
        components.second = secondsDateComponents.second
        
        return calendar.date(from: components)
    }
}
```

Then, I created my view used the `TimelineView` to update the text every minute after the data is refreshed:

```
struct LastUpdatedTextView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var store: DataStore
    
    var body: some View {
        if let nowWithSameSeconds = Date().withSameSeconds(asDate: store.lastUpdatedDate) {
            TimelineView(PeriodicTimelineSchedule(from: nowWithSameSeconds,
                                                  by: 60))
            { context in
                Text(store.lastUpdatedText(forDate: lastUpdatedDate))
            }
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple addresses this in [Build A Workout App](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10009) from WWDC21

They use `TimelineView` and `context.cadence == .live` to tell their formatter to not show milliseconds when the watch is in Alway on.

You could use that code to determine what to show.

```
struct TimerView: View {
    var date: Date
    var showSubseconds: Bool
    var fontWeight: Font.Weight = .bold
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 8.0, watchOS 8.0, iOS 15.0, *) {
            //The code from here is mostly from https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10009
            TimelineView(MetricsTimelineSchedule(from: date)) { context in
                ElapsedTimeView(elapsedTime: -date.timeIntervalSinceNow, showSubseconds: context.cadence == .live)
            }
        } else {
            Text(date,style: .timer)
                .fontWeight(fontWeight)
                .clipped()
        }
    }
}
@available(watchOSApplicationExtension 8.0, watchOS 8.0, iOS 15.0,*)
private struct MetricsTimelineSchedule: TimelineSchedule {
    var startDate: Date
    
    init(from startDate: Date) {
        self.startDate = startDate
        
    }
    
    func entries(from startDate: Date, mode: TimelineScheduleMode) -> PeriodicTimelineSchedule.Entries {
        PeriodicTimelineSchedule(from: self.startDate, by: (mode == .lowFrequency ? 1.0 : 1.0 / 30.0))
            .entries(from: startDate, mode: mode)
    }
}
struct ElapsedTimeView: View {
    var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = 0
    var showSubseconds: Bool = false
    var fontWeight: Font.Weight = .bold
    @State private var timeFormatter = ElapsedTimeFormatter(showSubseconds: false)
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(NSNumber(value: elapsedTime), formatter: timeFormatter)
            .fontWeight(fontWeight)
            .onChange(of: showSubseconds) {
                timeFormatter.showSubseconds = $0
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                timeFormatter = ElapsedTimeFormatter(showSubseconds: showSubseconds)
            })
    }
}
```