# How to write an effective TimerView in SwiftUI?

Tags: performance, swiftui

I wrote a simple timer view.

And I found it use 30% CPU on iPhone SE 2016 (or 12% CPU on Simulator.)

How to make a timer view with less CPU usage?

```swift
import SwiftUI
private var timer = Timer.publish (every: 0.01, on: .current, in: .common)
                         .autoconnect()

struct TimerView: View {
    @State var time: TimeInterval = 0
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(time.description)")
        .onReceive(timer) { time in
            self.time = time.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
// Implementation in UIKit, 12% CPU Usage on iPhone SE 2016
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let displaylink = CADisplayLink(target: self,
                                        selector: #selector(updateLabel))
        displaylink.add(to: .current,
                        forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
    }

    @objc func updateLabel(displaylink: CADisplayLink) {
        self.label.text = "\(displaylink.targetTimestamp)"
    }
}
```

SwiftUI TimelineView example, suggested by lorem ipsum.

```
// iOS 15 TimelineView, 22~25% CPU usage
import SwiftUI

struct TimerView2: View {
    let step = 0.0166 // 1.0/60fps
    var body: some View {
        TimelineView(.periodic(from: .now, by: step)) { timeline in
            Text("\(timeline.date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63425455/12299030?

Comment: The timer in that answer is advanced by one secs. What I need is advanced by 0.01 secs. In my real application, I use a timer to update the position of a waveform image while audio is playing.

Comment: TimelineView is I think the best way in iOS 15+ Look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383495/in-swiftui-on-apple-watch-what-is-the-best-way-to-update-a-string-that-describe/69384166#69384166

Comment: I tried TimelineView (see added example), it is about 22~25% CPU usage. I don't know who made Casio F91W Watch in 1989. But now I think he/she must be a genius.

Comment: It will likely be tough for SwiftUI since what it is doing is recreating the entire `View` vs just the `Text`. SwiftUI has gotten more efficient with its latest release but it still has a long way to go before it is as efficient as UIKit.

Comment: While I don't think it would make a difference, have you tried a `UIViewRepresentable`?

Comment: Does the CPU usage change in release mode?

Comment: All cpu usage number are tested in release mode. I tried UIViewRepresentable today. It is better.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use UIViewRepresentable to wrap UILabel. CPU usage drop from 22-25% to 16-18% on iPhone SE 2016. I guess Text from SwiftUI did some additional things (ex: updating layout). So it is slower.

So compare to UIKit (render 60fps text)

- 4% CPU usage is added by SwiftUI Text
- 5% CPU usage is added by SwiftUI & TimelineView

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct TimerView3: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        TimelineView(.periodic(from: .now, by: 0.01667)) { timeline in
            // CPU 12 - 13%
            //MyCALabel(text: "\(timeline.date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)")

            // CPU 16 - 18%
            //MyLabel(text: "\(timeline.date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)")

            // CPU 22 - 25%
            //Text("\(timeline.date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)")
        }
    }
}

struct MyCALabel: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        let textLayer = CATextLayer()
        textLayer.string = text
        textLayer.fontSize = 24
        textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        view.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)

        textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        if let textLayer = (uiView.layer.sublayers?[0]) as? CATextLayer {
            textLayer.string = text
        }
    }
}

struct MyLabel: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = text
        return label
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        if let label = uiView as? UILabel {
            label.text = text
        }
    }
}
```