# SwiftUI: How to create a multiple timer app with a list of timers and how to jump between the timer views

Tags: swift, xcode, listview, swiftui, timer

I just created a timer app for me and my friends with multiple timers. To navigate between these timers i created a list for each timer in an array of `timerObjects` instanzes.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    private let timers = [TimerObject(name: "Kuchen", duration: 15), TimerObject(name: "Atem anhalten", duration: 30), TimerObject(name: "Abflug", duration: 7200)]
   
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(timers, id: \.id) { timer in
                NavigationLink {
                    TimerView(timerObject: timer)
                } label: {
                    Text(timer.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `TimerView()` is just the view that handels and present the whole thing behind the timer.

My Problem now is now: if i start a timer in the `TimerView()` and than go back to the list and than go back to the started timer, i get a new instanz of my timer and the `TimerView()` don´t show me the started timer. My goal is to go back to the started timer!

To clarify my problem, I also recorded my problem once and uploaded it to youtube so that you can see it too:
[My problem on youtube](https://youtu.be/bdh-122-Jx0)

I would be very happy about help.
Best regards!

**Update for @JoakimDanielson:**

```
struct TimerView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = TimerViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.formatter.string(from: TimeInterval(viewModel.remainingSeconds))!)
                .font(.system(size: 78))
                .bold()
            
            TimerButtons(isRunning: $viewModel.isRunning) {
                viewModel.startTimer()
            } stopTimer: {
                viewModel.stopTimer()
            } resetTimer: {
                viewModel.resetTimer()
            }

        }
        .onReceive(viewModel.timer) { _ in
            viewModel.updateTime()
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.onAppear()
        }
        .alert("Achtung", isPresented: $viewModel.isShownNotificationAlert) {
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Text("OK")
            }
            
            Button {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } label: {
                Text("Einstellungen")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
        } message: {
            Text("Du wirst nicht beim ablaufen des Timers benachrichtigt")
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have a dummy timerObject timer in my TimerViewModel because i don´t know how to pass a timerObject to my TimerViewModel class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The time should go in the view model and publish from there.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the kind answer. But, where can I find the view model?

Comment: You need to create that class yourself and it should conform to`ObservableObject` and it should hold the array you now have in your view as a `@Published` property

Comment: Please study [Apple’s SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) & [Stanford’s CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/). These will give you a good foundation to code in SwiftUI.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Is that all or do I need to do something after it?

Comment: @Yrb Thanks for the link I'll take a look. Could you still give me an example how I could solve my problem? I'm a bit new to SwiftUI but have been programming with UIKit for a while before.

Comment: I think you should research ObservableObject (and Published) and try to find a good tutorial on how to use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383495/in-swiftui-on-apple-watch-what-is-the-best-way-to-update-a-string-that-describe/69384166#69384166

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I know how to use ObserveableObject!!! But i want want to know what i´m supposed to to with this class

Comment: @loremipsum how is this helpful for me?

Comment: The point is that if you use the class correctly then you will have the same timer object in both views instead of creating new instances. You declare it as a StateObject in your main view

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I now have a good understanding of the ViewModel Pattern. So my task now is to pack all the logic from my TimerView() into my TimerViewModel() class and that's it? PS: Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, you should have as little logic as possible in the view and instead let the view model handle that

Comment: It is different it sounds like you are trying to use the provided Timer but that stops running easily and has other issues as you are experiencing. If you add a start and end time to the timer object you can easily calculate duration and the view in the link will make it appear that a timer is running.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have now packed my code logic (With the timer publisher) from TimerView() in a TimerViewModel() class and unfortunately it is not working so far. In addition, I had a question: I actually transfer a TimerObject to my TimerView() for each list line, but now I no longer need this TimerObject in my TimerView but in my TimerViewModel class. So how can I put the specific timeobject there?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this is my code now: Unfortunately, packing the logic into a model has not yet been successful. For the code look in my question