# Formatting milliseconds with a Timer in Swift and SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, timer, format, milliseconds

I have this function which can successfully convert a counter variable into a beautifully formatted minutes and seconds string. How can I extend this to a format displaying MM:SS:milliseconds ?

I thought perhaps to do `let milliseconds = Int(Double(seconds / 60) * 100)` and append it to the return. Any tips?

Note: my timer should be publishing with enough granularity `@State var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()`

```
func formatMmSs(counter: Double) -> String {
    let minutes = Int(counter) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(counter) % 60
    return String(format: "%02i:%02i", minutes, seconds)
}
```

Comment: First make sure to do NOT use the timer to measure elapsed time. Only use it to update the user interface. 1/30 of a second should be enough for displaying purposes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383495/in-swiftui-on-apple-watch-what-is-the-best-way-to-update-a-string-that-describe/69384166#69384166

Comment: what is a genuine native option for displaying elapsed time?

Comment: @Andre just store the start date and then get the time interval since now. The only issue is that would always return negative result. Just swap the dates to get positive result `Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to multiply your counter (number of seconds) times 1000,
truncating remainder dividing by 1000 and coerce the result to integer:

```
func formatMmSsMl(counter: Double) -> String {
    let minutes = Int((counter/60).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
    let seconds = Int(counter.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
    let milliseconds = Int((counter*1000).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1000))
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d.%03d", minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
}
```

---

Or implemented as a computed property for BinaryFloatingPoint types:

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
    var intValue: Int { Int(self) }
    var minutesSecondsMilliseconds: String {
        String(format: "%02d:%02d.%03d",
               (self / 60).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60).intValue,
               truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60).intValue,
               (self * 1000).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1000).intValue)
    }
}
```

---

You can also custom format the floating point. No need to coerce to integer as follow:

```
extension TimeInterval {
    var minutesSecondsMilliseconds: String {
        String(format: "%02.0f:%02.0f.%03.0f",
               (self / 60).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60),
               truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60),
               (self * 1000).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1000).rounded(.down))
    }
}
```

---

```
123.45678.minutesSecondsMilliseconds   // "02:03.456"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is keep using your approach also following Leo approach,

```
func formatMmSs(counter: Double) -> String {
    let minutes = Int(counter) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(counter) % 60
    let milliseconds = Int(counter*1000) % 1000
    return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%03d", minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
}
```